# Jaxb binding file being ignored

Tags: binding, jaxb, xjc

I having a bit of trouble building JAXB bindings fora  set of schemas and its driving me a bit batty.  Here is the schema in question (it is just one of may schema in this particular build):

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
<attribute name="lang" type="language">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>In due course, we should install the relevant ISO 2- and 3-letter
            codes as the enumerated possible values . . .</documentation>
    </annotation>
</attribute>
<attribute name="space" default="preserve">
    <simpleType>
        <restriction base="NCName">
            <enumeration value="default"/>
            <enumeration value="preserve"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
</attribute>
<attributeGroup name="specialAttrs">
    <attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
    <attribute ref="xml:space"/>
</attributeGroup>
```

xjc is claiming that the attributes declared above are already declared elsewhere:

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] 'lang' is already defined
  line 26 of file:../../gml/3.1.1/smil/xml-mod.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 88 of http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd

[ERROR] 'space' is already defined
  line 34 of file:../../gml/3.1.1/smil/xml-mod.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 95 of http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd

[ERROR] 'specialAttrs' is already defined
  line 39 of file:../../gml/3.1.1/smil/xml-mod.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 111 of http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Doing a bit of research would lead me to believe that the problem is that I need a binding file to resolve the duplicate attributes....and I have one :

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../../gml/3.1.1/smil/xml-mod.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='lang']">
        <jaxb:property name="langAttribute"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='space']">
        <jaxb:property name="spaceAttribute"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attributeGroup[@name='specialAttrs']">
        <jaxb:property name="specialAttrsAttribute"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Yet the problem persists.  The error message with or without the bindings file is the same. I know the file is being used , because if I mess up the xpath for the node selector I get an error message. It's like xjc knows the bindings file is there but ignores it.

Here's the command line that fails to build the bindings:

```
C:\tools\jaxb-ri-20110512\bin\xjc -episode ..\..\..\common.ogc -d ..\..\..\src -p com.ogc.bindings -b ..\..\..\bindings.xsd -catalog ..\..\..\ogc.cat -extension  sosAll.xsd
```

I have tried this with both the jdk6 native jaxb (2.0) and jaxb 2.2.4 (I installed the jaxb-api.jar in the endorsed directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**XJC (bundled with JDK), ignores binding file, if the path to the binding file or the XSD / WSDL is too long.**

Issue observed and confirmed on Oracle 64 bit JDK 1.6.0.45, on Windows 7 ultimate and on Linux, XJC (bundled with JDK), ignores binding file, if the path to the binding file is too long.

I did NOT have the time to do detail research on the issue; I solved my problem by simply shortening the svn checkout path. It was the most bizarre issue - I could not reproduce the problem on my Windows 8 Laptop and on Linux, but on a Windows 7 workstation, build kept on failing. I identified this issue by confirming that other then path, there is NO difference between Windows 8 LAPTOP, where the build works, vs. Windows 7 Ultimate where the path is a bit long (6 characters -> /trunk).

Problem was solved without any code, configuration, xml schema or binding file change. Posting here so that others who may run into this, have a bit of easier time then me.

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is an issue with namespace collision, you dont have a namespace defined for your schema elements and it seems you are using names for your attributes that are in conflict with the ones defined in xml's schema (xml.xsd)